# I am attempting to calculate the Silhouette Coefficients for 20000 clustered data points

Tags: python, cluster-computing

[note: Stack is forcing me to indent some non-code blocks it detects as code]

I am attempting calculate the bolded for each xi and store it in a list

For each data point xi:

```
**A = average distance of xi to other points in same cluster.**  
B = Minimum (the average distances of xi to other points in each different cluster)  
S = (B-A) / max(A,B)  
SC=SC+S
SC = SC / number of data points.
```

The problem I'm running across is that my code works when data is small; however, it runs indefinitely when the data it has to sift through is 20000.
Each list in "data" represents: [#, not_important, x-value, y-value]
Each element in clusters maps to # in data.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as la
data = [[0,0,1,2,], [1, 0, 5 ,7], [2, 0, 1, 9], [3, 1, 2, 0], [4,0,22,5]]
clusters = [[1,2], [3,4]]

A = list()
for c in clusters:
    A_i = list()
    for i in c:
        x = data[i]
        a = 0
        for j in range(len(c)):
            d_i = np.array(x[2:])
            d_j = np.array(data[c[j]][2:])
            a += la.norm(d_i - d_j)
        a = a / len(c)
        A_i.append(a)
    A.append(A_i)
print A


# Output: [[2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979], [10.307764064044152, 10.307764064044152]]
```

^ this works

However when using real data of over 20000 observations, it fails to finish running:
i.e. of real data:

```
data = [[0.0, 5.0, -13.9383184, -20.94943593], [1.0, 0.0, -26.2837148, 16.83670948], [2.0, 4.0, 36.89961228, -19.90378864], ...]

cluster = [[5, 6, 8, 14, ...], [0, 1, 7, 10,...], [2, 3, 4, 9, ...]]

where len(data) = 20000  
and len(cluster[0]) + len(cluster[1]) + len(cluster[2] = 20000
```

Comment: you can add a print statement to check at what stage the code is at. Your code could be fine, it just maybe taking a whole lot of time.

Comment: I added a print A_i statement and it appears to be working. Are there any modules I can use to help make this faster?